# Find the order of U(44) using Euler ϕ-function, also find the order of 5 in U(44)

Tags: abstract-algebra

Find the order of U(44) using Euler ϕ-function, also find the order of 5 in U(44).

Must use Euler ϕ-function to do this.

This is my proof I was wondering if anybody can check it to see if it is right.

Using euler product formula

U(n) = U(P1^k1) . U(P2^k2).......U(Pr^k^r) where P1,P2,.......Pr are prime numbers

also Euler function

U(P^k) = P^k(1-1/P)

44 can be written as 2^2 * 11

therefore

U(44) = u(2^2 *11) = 44* (1-(1/2)) * (1-(1/11))

= 44 * 1/2 * 10/11

= 20

hence order of U(44) is 20

Comment: $\varphi(44)=\varphi(4\cdot 11)=(2)(10)$.

Comment: For the order of $5$, you could work separately modulo $4$ and modulo $11$. Things are very easy mod $4$, since $5\equiv 1\pmod{4}$. If you want to use the Euler $\varphi$-function for this part, maybe the fact that the order of $a$ must divide $\varphi(44)$ will be helpful.

Comment: You might find the Carmichael function $\lambda$ useful for the second part; the maximum order of any element of U(44) is 10, and $5\equiv 7^2 \bmod 44$.

Answer (score 0):

The calculations you perform are correct and the right ones. However, you should not use $U$ but rather $\phi$.
By $U(n)$ one means the group, so some collection of elements. 
It is not right to say $U(p^k)= p^k (1-1/p)$. What is correct is that the number of elements in $U(p^k)$, so the order of it, is  $p^k (1-1/p)$.